# how to keep sensitive data out of a sinatra app on github?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have an account_sid and account_token that I use to communicate with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api). I want to push my app to Heroku, but I obviously can't have those credentials up on github.

I know that Rails uses [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for storing sensitive account info as environment variables, but I can't find an equivalent for Sinatra.

Comment: I use the gem [ahoward/sekrets](https://github.com/ahoward/sekrets) to store sekret keys on heroku. My buddy did a refactor of the readme to to make it easy to set up: [here](https://github.com/woodall/sekrets/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: You could use `heroku config:set` to set environment variables, then access those within Ruby.

Comment: @MattLeonard Your buddy provided instructions on how to assign sekrets to variable in a Rails app, but left that info out for non-Rails apps. Do you have experience with that? I'm used to the ENV["BLAH_BLAH"] format, but I know that's not gonna work here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gem that may work for you.

https://github.com/chytreg/sinatra-figaro

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem https://github.com/SergXIIIth/config_env

Features:

1. Use pure Ruby for environment configuration
2. Upload to Heroku

Comment: I'm sorta confused by this documentation. How do I set variables, and how do I use them elsewhere? It looks like the first string after "set" creates the key, and the second string creates the value, but I'm not able to get it working when I reference them elsewhere.

    I have --- "set 'account_sid', '3w9h3r98r89h32rh'"

But referencing it elsewhere as ENV['account_sid'] does not work.

Comment: Sorry for that. I update gem. Add more nicer Readme. Add feature to auto load configuration file (please follow Readme instruction), it should solve `nil` into `ENV['account_sid']`. Please submit issues to https://github.com/SergXIIIth/config_env/issues. Thanks.